# Flow (type) doesn't respect manual check I do for a class property

Tags: javascript, flowtype

An example:

```
class MyClass {
  foo: ?string;
  constructor(foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
  }

  doSomething() {
    if (!this.foo) throw new Error();
    console.log('hi'); // if I comment this line, I get no errors!
    const myFoo: string = this.foo;
  }
}
```

I get the following error:

> 12:       const myFoo: string = this.foo;
>                                ^ Cannot assign `this.foo` to `myFoo` because null or undefined [1](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBjGBDAzrsAWQE8BhHfMAb1TDCjjgC4wB+XAFwCcBLAOwDmAblpgMcPpy4BXDBzhcAFAzgBKaqICQHABY9cAOhVgAvPUYi6AX3R0AJnADKcALYBTXfwGL1NOnR4oMEUAQk9DFXVdLkQwPjckAFEuGKVVS39xSTgYNwN4bwByPUL0sGBgMECwAEkxV3c+DjBwsBh+NwAaWrABDzi4MDcUhVwQrSzOMBdiADFGFikvUxa9CItRGysgA) is incompatible with string [2].

You can see it live [here](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBjGBDAzrsAWQE8BhHfMAb1TDCjjgC4wB+XAFwCcBLAOwDmAblpgMcPpy4BXDBzhcAFAzgBKaqICQHABY9cAOhVgAvPUYi6AX3R0AJnADKcALYBTXfwGL1NOnR4oMEUAQk9DFXVdLkQwPjckAFEuGKVVS39xSTgYNwN4bwByPUL0sGBgMECwAEkxV3c+DjBwsBh+NwAaWrABDzi4MDcUhVwQrSzOMBdiADFGFikvUxa9CItRGysgA).

As you can see, I do make sure that `this.foo` is set. However, if after the check, there is any code executed, although that code doesn't do anything, it ignores my check.

Answer (score 1):

Flow does not allow this because as far as it is concerned, the `console.log()` call could change the value of `this.foo`, which is right. Flow could theoretically special-case `console.log` since it isn't like to have side-effects, but it could be any function call there really. If you want this to work you need to grab the value first, e.g.

```
doSomething() {
  const foo = this.foo;
  if (!foo) throw new Error();
  console.log('hi');
  const myFoo: string = foo;
}
```

or

```
doSomething() {
  if (!foo) throw new Error();
  const foo = this.foo;
  console.log('hi');
  const myFoo: string = foo;
}
```

since there is no way for the type of the `foo` variable to change since it isn't reassigned anywhere.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I was afraid that what's happening, but hoping that Flow figures out that my `console.log` line doesn't change anything. Anyway, I'm trying to come up with a better solution to my case (rather than adding a new variable `const foo = this.foo;`), which, in my case, `this.foo` is a read-only variable. I tried to change `foo: ?string;` to `+foo: ?string;`, which tells Flow that this variable is read-only, but I still see the error. (I guess because Flow doesn't know that this read-only notation was really enforced).

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by Flow's [Refinement Validations](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/refinements/#toc-refinement-invalidations)

That also provides an example workaround.

Read only variables aren't necessarily immutable.  For example, `delete this.foo` doesn't cause an error (which might be a bug in flow because it seems like a clear violation of the type, but is distinct from reassignment  - [bug report](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/5927)).

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I hope they'll address this in the future. It doesn't sound difficult to check whether the calls in between change the value. (e.g. when I use IntelliJ to search for a variable it shows me all places in the code that change that variable).